# Need a way to convert .RAR including embedded .RARs if they exist

Tags: windows, batch-file, rar

I have a large number of .RAR files, some of which include embedded .RAR files like blahpart1.rar,blahpart2.rar. I am looking for a way to convert all of the .RAR files including any embedded .RAR files since almost all are in winrar 4 format and winrar 5 has better compression. The size difference would normally be minimal but because of the large number of files, it should be significant.
winrar has a "CV" option to convert the high level archive but not any embedded.
This is what I came up with so far but it is definitely flawed.

```sh
@echo off
@for %%i in (*.rar) do (
    @if /I exist z:\temp\stop exit
    @echo Now Processing "%%i"
    @md "%%~ni"
    @cd "%%~ni"
    @rar x ..\"%%i"
    @if /I exist *.rar (
        start /wait winrar cv *.rar -y -r -mt 4
    ) else (
        rar m "%%~ni.rar" -r
    )
    @ren *.rar "%%~ni.rar"
    @move ..\"%%i" \Unconverted
    @move *.rar \converted
    @cd ..
    @rd "\temp\%%~ni" /s/q
)
```

Because "if exist" doesn't have the ability to recursively look for .RAR files in subdirectories, the above batch file won't convert any embedded RAR files if they exist in BLAH\BLAHpart1.rar
Hopefully someone has some ideas.

Comment: Never quote partial paths, always quote whole ones, like `"..\%%~i"` instead of `..\"%%i"` (note the `~` removes potential surrounding quotes from the value of `%%i`, preventing "over-quotation"). *N. B.:* Remove the leading `@` from all but the first lines…

Comment: …or remove the first line, `@echo off`, change the next line to `@for %%i in (*.rar) do @(`, and remove all of the other leading `@` characters. Change both of your `if /I exist` to just `if exist` too, as `exist` is not case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks. I will cleanup my code so far.